# Timestamp data to offset to next sheet in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Instead of having timestamp data appear offset a cell, I'd like it to appear in another sheet. I wouldn't like to use .tocopy method because the data may be removed(archived) in the active working sheet; timestamp data should remain in the next sheet when data is removed from working sheet.

Code snippet below:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the sheet you want the date to be put into, just get a reference to that sheet, and set the value.

```
var sheetToWriteTo = s.getSheetByName('sheetName');
sheetToWriteTo.getRange(put range here).setValue(new Date());
```